# ajax php example not working on local web server mac

Tags: ajax, apache

I am trying to learn ajax on my mac apache server using the example code in http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_php.asp  .  But it is not working on my local server as desired( I am using CODA 2 in mac 10.8). I have no idea what is going wrong. Can someone help me with this.

Comment: run `apachectl status` command in terminal and see if apache is running. If running, run `tail -5 /var/log/httpd/error_log` and post the response here

Answer (score 0):

It may be a port issue.  I run [MAMP](http://www.mamp.info/en/index.html) (which I just switched to from WAMPP, and I love it).  By default it runs Apache via port 8888 and MYSQL via port 8889.  I had to switch this to ports 80 and 3306, respectively, to get everything working properly.

But if you can run any more basic php calls, I'd rule out this suggestion.

Comment: Deo-MacBook:~ admin$ apachectl status
Go to http://localhost:80/server-status in the web browser of your choice.
Note that mod_status must be enabled for this to work.
Deo-MacBook:~ admin$ tail -5 var/log/httpd/errorlog
tail: var/log/httpd/errorlog: No such file or directory

Comment: I dont see any httpd/error_log file bing created in /var/log after i try to run the ajax php example.

Comment: Sounds like the path to your file is incorrect.  To get the right absolute path, go to the file you want and drag it into the Terminal.  The terminal will automatically generate the absolute path.  Depending on your configurations you may need to fineagel the paths.  For instance, if the file being referenced is a child of the root directory (in this case, localhost), then you could trim off the path to the root.